# How to create a custom address attribute for customer and show that in edit address in admin?

Tags: admin, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, customer-address, customer-address-attribute

I want to create a custom customer address attribute called **customer_custom_id** in the below address.( check the below image.). how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by create a data patch using a custom module.

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\CustomAttributes\Setup\Patch\Data;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class CreatedCustomAdressAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{


private $moduleDataSetup;
private $attributeSetFactory;
private $customerSetupFactory;
private $attribute;


public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    Attribute $attribute
) {
    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attribute = $attribute;
}

public function apply()
{
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $customerAddressEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
    $attributeSetId = $customerAddressEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'customer_custom_id', [
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'label'         => 'Customer Custom Field',
        'input'         => 'text',
        'required'      =>  false,
        'visible'       =>  true,
        'user_defined'  =>  true,
        'sort_order'    =>  13,
        'position'      =>  13,
        'system'        =>  0,
    ]);


    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'customer_custom_id');

    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'adminhtml_checkout',
        'adminhtml_customer_address',
        'customer_account_edit',
        'customer_address_edit',
    ]);
    
    $this->attribute->save($attribute);


    return $this;
}

public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}

public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}
}
```

[image]